# subtracting multiple columns from each other

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a large dataset and I want to subtract specific columns from each other based on their position. I want to subtract column 2 from column 8, column 3 from column 9 and column 4 from column 10.

Thanks a lot

Magnus

```
structure(list(Stamp_summertime = structure(c(1546684744, 1546685858, 
                                              1546687004, 1547030061, 1547030835, 1547031816), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                                        "POSIXt")), X26.013 = c(0.138461, 0.138461, 0.138461, 0.144421, 
                                                                                                                                                0.144421, 0.144421), X27.024 = c(0.0752111, 0.0752111, 0.0752111, 
                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0426819, 0.0426819, 0.0426819), X33.031 = c(3.75788, 3.75788, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                               3.75788, 3.12581, 3.12581, 3.12581), jar_camp = c("1_pf1.1", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "2_pf1.1", "3_pf1.1", "1_pf2.1", "2_pf2.1", "3_pf2.1"), jar = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           12L, 23L, 1L, 12L, 23L), .Label = c("1", "10_blank", "11", "12", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "13", "14", "15", "16_blank", "17", "18", "19", "2", "20_blank", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "3", "30_blank", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38_blank", "39", "4", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "40", "41", "42", "43", "44_blank", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "5_blank", "blank_50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "6", "7", "8", "9", "X_blank"), class = "factor"), campaign = c("pf1.1", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "pf1.1", "pf1.1", "pf2.1", "pf2.1", "pf2.1"), i.X26.013 = c(0.144658, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.21502, 0.458296, 0.191571, 0.0789067, 0.711814), i.X27.024 = c(0.0595547, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0651149, 0.146772, 0.0997815, 0.0539976, 0.185398), i.X33.031 = c(5.4066, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                3.30406, 18.0479, 6.13854, 1.3028, 22.2226)), sorted = "Stamp_summertime", class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000237a3d91ef0>)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create 2 vectors of position and subtract the columns directly. Since you have `data.table` we use `..column_number` to select columns by position.

```
library(data.table)
col1group <- 2:4
col2group <- 8:10

df[, ..col1group] - df[, ..col2group])
```

If you want to add them as new columns to original data you can rename them and `cbind`

```
cbind(df, setNames(df[, ..col1group] - df[, ..col2group],
                   paste0(names(df)[col1group], '_diff')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following computes the subtractions in the question.

```
library(data.table)

nms <- names(df1)
iCols <- grep("^i\\.", nms, value = TRUE)
Cols <- sub("^i\\.", "", iCols)

df1[, lapply(seq_along(Cols), function(i) get(Cols[i]) - get(iCols[i]))]
#           V1         V2        V3
#1: -0.0061970  0.0156564  -1.64872
#2: -0.0765590  0.0100962   0.45382
#3: -0.3198350 -0.0715609 -14.29002
#4: -0.0471500 -0.0570996  -3.01273
#5:  0.0655143 -0.0113157   1.82301
#6: -0.5673930 -0.1427161 -19.09679
```

---

Following [Ronak Shah's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63899422/8245406) answer I realized that the code below also works.

```
df1[, ..Cols] - df1[, ..iCols]
```

The numeric results are the same but the column names are the vector `Cols`.

To create new columns, try

```
newCols <- paste(Cols, "diff", sep = "_")
df1[, (newCols) := lapply(seq_along(Cols), function(i) get(Cols[i]) - get(iCols[i]))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
idx <- c(2, 3, 4)
jdx <- c(8, 9, 10)
```

Using `lapply()` and column binding the list:

```
setNames(do.call("cbind", lapply(seq_along(idx), function(i){
      df[, jdx[i], drop = FALSE] - df[, idx[i], drop = FALSE]
    }
  )
), c(paste("x", jdx, idx, sep = "_")))
```

Using `sapply()` and coercing vectors to a data.frame:

```
setNames(data.frame(sapply(seq_along(idx), function(i){
      df[, jdx[i], drop = FALSE] - df[, idx[i], drop = FALSE]
    }
  )
), c(paste("x", jdx, idx, sep = "_")))
```

Using `Map()` and `Reduce()` and column binding to original data.frame:

```
cbind(df, setNames(Reduce(cbind, Map(function(i){
    df[, jdx[i], drop = FALSE] - df[, idx[i], drop = FALSE]
  }, seq_along(idx))), c(paste("x", jdx, idx, sep = "_"))))
```